# Add own custom method to DoctrineMigrations

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine-migrations

Hi I would like to create my own custom method which I could use in the migration class. I mean something like this:

MigrationTraitFile.php

```
trait MigrationTrait {
    public function addAdditionalTable() {
        ...
    }
```

VersionXXX.php

```
class VersionXXX {
    use MigrationTrait;
    public function up() {
        $this->addAdditionalTable()
    }
```

So the trait should addSql to create Table in my migration class. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Since the trait doesn't/shouldn't have any context, you pass in a parameter:

Trait:

```
use Doctrine\DBAL\Migrations\AbstractMigration;

trait MigrationTrait {
    public function addAdditionalTable(AbstractMigration $migration) {
        $migration->addSql('...');
    }
}
```

Version:

```
use Doctrine\DBAL\Migrations\AbstractMigration;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\Schema;

class VersionXXX extends AbstractMigration {
    use MigrationTrait;
    public function up(Schema $schema) {
        $this->addAdditionalTable($this)
    }
}
```